# match word enclosed brackets and inner spaces in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm trying to match words with enclosed brackets without inner spaces with this regex:
`/(?<=\{\{).*?(?=}})/g`

some examples like: `{{ test }} {{test}} {{ test}} {{test }}`
but my regex takes out string with its white space that i don't want it. like `[space]test[space]` `[space]test` `test[space]`

I want strings without any white space before and after of them. that all of them return `test`.

Comment: What would be the problem with a capture _\{\{ ?(.*?) ?}}_ ... ?  The look-around creates an error when deferring the optional space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match word "test" without surrounding spaces in all four examples, you can use following regex:

```
(?<={{\s*)(?=\S).*?(?=\s*}})
```

Here:

- `(?<={{\s*)` checks that match is preceded by `{{` and any number of whitespaces,
- `(?=\S)` checks that match begins with something other than space,
- `.*?` matches any symbols, smallest possible amount,
- `(?=\s*}})` checks that match is followed by any number of whitespaces and `}}`.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/ALGkvJ/1).

Notice, if it is guaranteed that your brackets contain at least one nonwhitispace symbol, use `(?<={{\s*)\S.*?(?=\s*}})` instead, as it should have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`/(?<={)\w+(?=})/g`

All you need is a positive lookbehind `(?<={)` and lookahead `(?=})`. Then make sure there are characters (and no spaces) in between using `\w+`: